# Is there a way to pair 2 columns of data with one in SQL?

Tags: sql, search

I have basically 2 tables of data.

Table 1

```
|ColumnA|
|-------|
|123    |  
|123    |    
|122    |     
|123    |     
|001    |       
|002    |    
|002    |      
|001    |       
|123    |      
|122    |
```

Table 2:

```
|ColumnA|
|-------|    
|123    |     
|122    |     
|001    |     
|002    |    

|ColumnB|
|-------|
|A      |
|B      |
|C      |   
|D      |
```

The Expected result:
First column is from Table1 ColumnA

```
|ColumnA|FromTable2ColumnB|
|-------|-----------------|
|123    |  A              |
|123    |  A              | 
|122    |  B              |
|123    |  A              |
|001    |  C              |
|002    |  D              |
|002    |  D              |
|001    |  C              |
|123    |  A              |
|122    |  B              |
```

As you can see, column A of Table 1 is filled with duplum rows.
Unfortunately JOIN failed me so far, I am rather new to SQL.
So far I messed around with a code like this

```
select t1.ColumnA, t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB
from Table1 as t1
left outer join Table2 as t2
    on t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
```

The result is not something that works, I tried moving around a lot of things, but no success so far.

Currently, I am wasting time in excel and VLOOKUP, it works, but takes a long time, and I have a lot of tables ahead of me. Anyone has a suggestion?

EDIT:
I edited in what kinda result I am looking for.

Comment: Help us help you - share the expected result

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik 
Thank You! Completely forgot about that it was very late when I committed to making a post.

I edited in the expected result.

Comment: @eshirvana

I use DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: The query looks correct offhand, other than the fact you have an additional column of `t2.columnA`. Can you share the actual result you're getting and explain how it differs from the one you want to get?

Comment: @Mureinik

I don't think I can attach pictures, but in excel VLOOKUP works, and I get a result like in my example.

However!

SQL gives me about a 100x more rows of the same results.

Can I send you pictures somehow?

Comment: @Mureinik
The problem must be that there are duplicate rows, but I need those duplicate rows.

My dataframe is basically travels from point A to point B. I cannot remove them, since it would beat the purpose of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. Both of my tables had duplums. And that screwed up the logic.

Table1 was great, without the duplums it might as well shouldn't even exist, Table2 duplums had the issue. I filtered the data out from Table2 and it all works now with the same code.

Thank you for the help @Mureinik.